# reCaptcha - reading JSON response

Tags: asp.net, json, recaptcha

I get a response from the reCapture and need to read the "success" value, but get the error:

```
Public member 'success' on type 'Dictionary(Of String,Object)' not found.
```

Response

{ "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2017-02-20T13:55:01Z", "hostname": "domain.co.uk" }

I'm trying to access it using:

```
data.success
```

Full code

```
Dim Response As String = Request.Form("g-recaptcha-response")
Dim Valid As Boolean = False
Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(Convert.ToString("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" & SecretKey & "&response=") & Response), HttpWebRequest)
Try
    Using wResponse As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()

        Using readStream As New StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream())
            Dim jsonResponse As String = readStream.ReadToEnd()
            Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim data As Object = js.Deserialize(Of Object)(jsonResponse)
            Valid = Convert.ToBoolean(data.success)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return Valid
Catch ex As WebException
    Throw ex
End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer in the end so in case this helps anyone it's:

```
data("success")
```

Rather than

```
data.success
```